# How can I have my .bashrc only invoke TMUX if it exists on my system?

Tags: tmux, bashrc

I use tmux on most boxes, but not all.

I have the following line in my .bashrc file:

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```

which invoke tmux if it exists.

I *thought* the `[ -z $TMUX ]` meant that it would only be used if tmux exists.

However on another system, without tmux, I get

-bash: exec: tmux: not found

and the login attempt fails

On my main system I see

```
$ echo $TMUX
/private/var/folders/ks/266xy5lj7x35gfj4csc66444b48rvq/T/tmux-373580663/default,55084,4
```

I also tried just `[ $TMUX ]` (i.e. no `-z`) but that didn't help

I'm also looking for a robust solution that works in Ubuntu as well as OSX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you do `echo $TMUX`, while in a `tmux` session? Because `TMUX` is only set, when in a session.

Try that instead:

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && command -v tmux >/dev/null && TERM=xterm-256color exec tmux
```

Comment: A cleaner solution is `which tmux &>/dev/null && ...`. Capturing the output and testing if empty is just dirty :-)

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, I adapted it to your comment ;)

Comment: @polym  which(1) is an external program used to search PATH for an executable. It behaves differently on different systems and you can't rely on a useful exit code; use (from most to least portable) ''command -v'' or ''type -P'' (to find the path) or ''hash'' (to check) instead. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081

Comment: Another nitpick: `TERM=xterm-256color exec tmux` :-)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Depends on how this is being implemented. If this is simply being placed at the top of the `.bashrc`, then you are correct, it's a problem. A complete solution would involve a combination of checking to see if `$TMUX` is empty, and if the executable is present.

Comment: Yeah, it was better the first way. I upvoted it.

Comment: @val0x00ff , VolkerSiegel, patrick : how about now?

Comment: Better! Warning comment removed.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It's a legit warning :). Haven't thought about that at first, so it's great advice!

Comment: @Patrick No, [don't use `which`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then).

Comment: @Gilles That comment wasn't so much about using `which` as it was about not capturing the output (see original version of the answer). Yes, `command -v` is safer, but I wasn't addressing that bit :-)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so if you want to start `tmux` only when it exists in `$PATH` *and* when it isn't already running then you can do:

```
command -v tmux >/dev/null && ${TMUX+:} TERM=xterm-256color exec tmux
```

Shorter still:

```
tmux -c "${TMUX+!} :" 2>/dev/null && exec tmux -2
```

The second one asks `tmux` to return 0 if `${TMUX}` is not set `&&` if true, the  shell execs `tmux -2` to force 256-color. It will only ever return true if `tmux` can be run in `$PATH` and if the environment variablete `$TMUX` does not exist.

Comment: The "variable is not defined or we comment out the whole command with `:`" is interesting!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Changed it the comment above.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
which tmux && export TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```

If there is `tmux`, `which tmux` will evaluate to path to `tmux` binary, therefore to `true`. If there is no `tmux`, it will evaluate to empty string, so to `false`.

Comment: nah, it doesn't work, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146128/how-can-i-have-my-bashrc-only-invoke-tmux-if-it-exists-on-my-system/146130?noredirect=1#comment-236122